# Sum of Integers - 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

My question is related to the sum function in python.

So my code is

```
def black_jack(a, b):
    if sum(a, b) > 21:
        return 0
    else:
        return sum(a, b)


print black_jack(10, 5)
```

I get an error reading:

```
'int' object is not iterable
```

Can someone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: sum takes an iterable object such as a list so if you want to use sum then do `sum([a,b])`. Look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)

Comment: Basically, that's not what `sum` is for, `sum` is for the total of a list of tuple or other iterable. Don't get ahead of yourself :)

Comment: or you can just do `a+b`

Comment: I think you are looking for this: `int.__add__(a,b)` however, I would not use that. I would just use the plus sign operator.

Comment: Thanks, knew it was gonna be simple.

Comment: python can be tricky :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sum):

> **sum(iterable[, start])**
>
> Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. start defaults to `0`. The iterable‘s items are
>   normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string.

So you have to pass an iterable as argument, not an int!

`sum((a, b))` should work correctly.

This is a function which is intended to be used when you have many values stored in a list (for example), if you want to sum two values, you should simply use `a + b`.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just the following?

```
def black_jack(a, b):
    if a + b > 21:
        return 0
    else:
        return a + b

print black_jack(10, 5)
```

In Blackjack, one can have much more than just two cards, but with your example, it appears that you assume that a hand can have only two cards. If you allow for a variable number of cards, then you'd need to use an iterable object as others have suggested:

```
def black_jack(values):
    total = sum(values)
    return 0 if total > 21 else total

print black_jack(10, 5)
```

From the documentation for [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

> **`sum(`**`iterable`**`[,`**`start`**`])`**
>
> Sums start and the items of an *iterable* from left to right and returns the total. *start* defaults to `0`. The *iterable*'s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string.
>
> For some use cases, there are good alternatives to [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum). The preferred, fast way to concatenate a sequence of strings is by calling `''.join(sequence)`. To add floating point values with extended precision, see [`math.fsum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.fsum). To concatenate a series of iterables, consider using [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).
>
> *New in version 2.3.*

Answer (score 1):

**sum** is builtin function, look at the documentation:

```
In [1]: sum?
Docstring:
sum(sequence[, start]) -> value

Return the sum of a sequence of numbers (NOT strings) plus the value
of parameter 'start' (which defaults to 0).  When the sequence is
empty, return start.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

so you need to pass it a iterable! :
**solution1**

```
sum([a, b]) #list
```

**solution2**

```
sum((a, b)) #tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

sum expects iterable object (like list). So the code should be:

```
def black_jack(a, b):
    if sum([a, b]) > 21:
        return 0
    else:
        return sum([a, b])

print black_jack(10, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum` takes first argument as a list.Here you are:

```
def black_jack(a, b):
    if (sum([a], b) > 21):
        return 0
    else:
        return sum([a], b)


print black_jack(10, 5)
```